# I am having trouble with streamreader in c#

Tags: c#

I am having a little trouble with the streamreader.

I am opening emails from the file dialog, and those emails are placed inside a listbox. 
each letter in the emails, are on one line, as shown in the picture below.

I want the emails to be on one line, can some one help me, this is giving me a headache.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofg = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofg.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
    if (ofg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var fileName = ofg.FileName;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
        var line = sr.ReadToEnd();        

        foreach (var l in line)
            listBox1.Items.Add(l.ToString());

        sr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[image: example here]

Answer (score 1):

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines( fileName );

        foreach (var l in lines )
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add( l );
        }
```

assuming that you have

```
        email1@email1.com
        email2@email2.com
```

in your file (this is what I understood from your description).

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as follow:

> ```
> using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
> {
>       string line;
>
>       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
>       {
>           listBox1.Items.Add(line.ToString()); 
>       }
> }
> ```

This reads all the lines in the file and adds it to the listbox line by line.

Answer (score 0):

string containl chars, so `foreach (var l ...)` iterates through chars in line.
You should replace your foreach with

```
foreach( var email in line.Split(' '))
```

In case your emails separated with spaces.
Another approach would be File.[ReadAllLines](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx&ei=VRcuUN2wIYTmtQbLvoHIBw&usg=AFQjCNHa9hxf4WoDNnX9lbiQMF8NIPioqQ&sig2=nRc_yYv19n3Lv8BI-Dr0eQ&cad=rjt), in case emails in your file is on separate lines...

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName))) 
{
   while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
   {
      listBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
   }
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline